# How to load multiple views on each button tap when using a UISegmentedVIew

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, tap

I have a UISegmentedControl with a 3 button layout that I use to control a 3 Views layout that I have
I am able to detect the taps on each button but how to I load and show the views that I want for each view

They have to be loaded 1 time and shown upon the tap of the ID of the UISegmentedView

It's a edit-save situation with multiple pages..

Answer (score 1):

Use the selectedSegmentIndex property of the UISegmentedControl object.

```
if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"segment 1");
    if (view1 == NULL) {
        view1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:view1.view];
    }

    else {
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:view1.view];
    }
}

else {
    NSLog(@"segment 2");
    if (view2 == NULL) {
        view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:view2.view];
    }

    else {
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:view2.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a problem with this, as my view1 and view2 will be a class of a UIView UIViewController that has a class defined and a XIB, self.view addSubview:view1];  expects a UIView type. How can I use what I have ?

Comment: Edited above. If you have the XIB for the two view controllers then you might want to use the initWithNibName: bundle: method to alloc init.

Comment: Already did but I want them as subviews and to appear above the tabs. so once initialized I did  [self.view addSubview:detailFirstViewControler.view]; and  [self.view addSubview:detailSecondViewControler.view]; but that brings to front ALL the view, I can't see the containing one. My ideea is to reuse some XIB files as multiple tabs. I tried to resize the frame but nothing..it still full screens the entire XIB

Comment: Are you setting the sub-views' frames properly?

Comment: i'm doing this :  - (id)initWithNibName ---------       detailPatientController = [[PatientEditViewControler alloc] initWithNibName:@"PatientEditViewControler" bundle:nil];
         then         [detailPatientController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)] ;
          then         [self.view addSubview:detailPatientController.view];
          and it shows in fullscreeen the detailPatientController ...hides the original self.view

Comment: Something is wrong with your self.view.Maybe you're doing it somewhere else. The hierarchy is simple. Here: ParentView (self) -> UISegmentedControl is one subview to parentView with its frame and similarly all your 3 views are also sub views to parentView with their frame. So self.view is always the parentView object's view. Its just a two level view hierarchy.