# Loading another NIB into one subview of a UIVIEW

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, xib, subview

I have a simple question that I couldn't see it answered on the whole site,

One XIB file that has a UIView as the main,

in it has another UIView that's connected to one IBoutlet so I can assign it later to load a view from another XIB file. That assignment doesn't work.. it remains blank...

```
@interface Subclass : UIViewController { 
        UIView *view1; 
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@end
```

i linked view1 to the subview in the xib file
in implementation in initWithNibName I'm loading Other XIB file and use it's view and assigning it to the view1. Still this doesn't work...

```
detailControler = [[XibViewControler alloc] initWithNibName:@"XibViewControler" bundle:nil];
 //one aproach
[self.view1 addSubview: detailControler.view]; 
//another aproach
[self setView1:detailControler.view];
```

If I'm adding the subview programaticaly to [self.view addSubview:detailControler.view] and set a frame to it, it will go fullscreen, and hide the original view.

I also had a different approach that didn't work 
[How to load multiple views on each button tap when using a UISegmentedVIew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476370/how-to-load-multiple-views-on-each-button-tap-when-using-a-uisegmentedview)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually set up a `UIView` inside another view, although I'm not entirely sure if it's best practice or anything like that:

```
if(newViewController == nil){
  newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithCoder:nil];
}
newViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
if([newViewController.view superview] == nil){
  [view1 addSubview:newViewController.view];
}
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: doing this with a new clean project it worked, it just doesn't work in my 70 class project...for some reason.. what is wierd is that I did create the view from scratch as I did with the new project...

Comment: Thats weird. At least it's working with a new project though!

Comment: ok, I've added this in the main project and it works..actually it worked from starters...what it doesn't do it doesn't clip on the Frame boundaries  [detailPatientController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 50)];   ..it ignores the 100,50 ..but it does offest by 50,50 ... On the separate project.. it actually clipped on the frame boundaries wihtout no problem.. Do you know what setting I have to disable or enable?

Comment: OK I see what the problem is ..the background UIImageView doesn't clip to frame.. it's set to Scale to Fit .. and it will show as original. I will have to redefine it's frame also :)